# Azure Data Factory Bulk Insert using Table Control - Schedule Trigger to a specific table based on data column into table control

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to known if it's possible to execute trigger to specific tables configured into bulk insert table control in sql server.

Obs: I am using look up to get query from table control and for each to load table by table.

reference of my pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-bulk-copy-with-control-table

Comment: Could you please add sample data and provide your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I created a pipeline, and I crated lookup to take the list of the table from my database.
Database:
[image]

Pipeline:

[image]

LookUp:

[image]

I have created AzureSqlDatabase1 linked dataset for the source of LookUP.

Image for reference:

[image]

I have used below query to retrieve the list of tables in my database:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

[image]

Data preview of lookup:

[image]

ForEach:
I have used below code to retrieve the output of lookup into forEach

```
@activity('GetPartionList').output.value
```

[image]

I have created one copy activity in forEach
Image for reference:

[image]

CopyActivity:
Source of copyActivity:
I have created two parameters in copy activity named schema and table and given dynamic values as mentioned below:

```
schema: @item().TABLE_SCHEMA
table: @item().TABLE_NAME
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I passed above parameters as directory of table in copyActivity linked dataset as mentioned below:

```
Table: @dataset.schema.@dataset.table
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I passed below query to retrieve all tables based on the condition

```
select * from @{item().TABLE_NAME} where PartitionID > 3 and PartitionID<10;
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Sink of copyActivity:
I have created blob lined dataset as target linked dataset and I have created parameter as filename and given below code to save the format of csv file

```
@concat(item().TABLE_SCHEMA,'_',item().TABLE_NAME,'.CSV')
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I executed the pipeline and it executed successfully.

Image for reference:

[image]

Output of Lookup:

[image]

All files are stored in blob container according to my query.

Image for reference:

[image]